# Pandas: replace repeated values with blanks groupby like

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I got dataframe with columns got groups of repeated values. What i want is to keep only first item in such columns.

I've tried `df = df.groupby(['author', 'key'])` but don't know how to correctly get all rows. With `df.first()` only first rows will be printed.

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [
['juli', 'JIRA-1', 'assignee'],
['juli', 'JIRA-1', 'assignee'],
['nick', 'JIRA-1', 'timespent'], 
['nick', 'JIRA-3', 'status'], 
['nick', 'JIRA-3', 'assignee'],
['tom', 'JIRA-1', 'comment'], 
['tom', 'JIRA-1', 'assignee'], 
['tom', 'JIRA-2', 'status']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['author', 'key', 'field']) 
#df = df.sort_values(by=['author', 'key'])

>>> df
  author     key      field
0   juli  JIRA-1   assignee
1   juli  JIRA-1   assignee
2   nick  JIRA-1  timespent
3   nick  JIRA-3     status
4   nick  JIRA-3   assignee
5    tom  JIRA-1    comment
6    tom  JIRA-1   assignee
7    tom  JIRA-2     status
```

what I got:

```
>>> df.groupby(['author', 'key']).first()
                   field
author key
juli   JIRA-1   assignee
nick   JIRA-1  timespent
       JIRA-3     status
tom    JIRA-1    comment
       JIRA-2     status
```

what I want:

```
juli   JIRA-1   assignee
                assignee
nick   JIRA-1  timespent
       JIRA-3     status
                assignee
tom    JIRA-1    comment
                assignee
       JIRA-2     status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need [`df.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to find duplicates and [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to assign blank spaces:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(['author','key']),['author','key']]=''
print(df)
```

---

```
  author     key      field
0   juli  JIRA-1   assignee
1                  assignee
2   nick  JIRA-1  timespent
3   nick  JIRA-3     status
4                  assignee
5    tom  JIRA-1    comment
6                  assignee
7    tom  JIRA-2     status
```

Comment: yes and that makes sense since we group by `['author', 'key']` , let me see if I can find anything for you

Comment: thanks, simply solved with `df.loc[df.duplicated(['author']),['author']]=''`

Comment: @VadimK great, yes, assigning blank seperately is one way. :)